# Parse xsi:type="" in Python using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xsi

I know there are a few similar questions but none of the solutions seemed to work.
I need to parse and XML file using python. I am using Elementree
I am trying to print the value X.
It is working as long as I am just looking for X-Values within EndPosition but I have to look for within all MoveToType. Is there someway to integrate that in Elementree.
Thanks!

XML file:

```
<MiddleCommand xsi:type="MoveToType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CommandID>19828</CommandID>
        <MoveStraight>false</MoveStraight>
        <EndPosition>
            <Point>
                <X>528.65</X>
                <Y>33.8</Y>
                <Z>50.0</Z>
            </Point>
            <XAxis>
                <I>-0.7071067811865475</I>
                <J>-0.7071067811865477</J>
                <K>-0.0</K>
            </XAxis>
            <ZAxis>
                <I>0.0</I>
                <J>0.0</J>
                <K>-1.0</K>
            </ZAxis>
        </EndPosition>
    </MiddleCommand>
```

Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


#tree = ET.parse("102122.955_prog_14748500480769929136.xml")
tree = ET.parse("Move_to.xml")
root = tree.getroot()


for Point in root.findall("./EndPosition/Point/X"):
    print(Point.text)



for Point in root.findall('.//{MoveToType}/Endposition/Point/X'):
    print(Point.text)
```

Comment: Is it the case that your real XML file has several `MiddleCommand` elements but only some of them have `xsi:type="MoveToType"` attributes?

Comment: Yes exactly I have several e.g MoveToType, MoveThroughType, PoitionTolerance... And all of them have Point, X,Y,Z. But i only want the ones from MoveToType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the wanted `X` value for `MiddleCommand` elements with `xsi:type="MoveToType"`. Note that you need to use the full namespace URI inside curly braces when getting the value of the attribute.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
tree = ET.parse("Move_to.xml")  # The real XML, with several MiddleCommand elements
    
for MC in tree.findall(".//MiddleCommand"):
    # Check xsi:type value and if it equals MoveToType, find the X value
    if MC.get("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type") == 'MoveToType':
        X = MC.find(".//X")
        print(X.text)
```

Comment: I copy pasted your Code but unfortunately it didnt work.

Comment: well it just didnt print anything

Comment: Then I have probably made some assumption that does not hold with your real XML document. Do you understand the concept of XML namespaces and why the code looks like it does?

Comment: I didnt not try it with my real XML document. I tried it with what part i posted (I copied that part from the main XML file to a seperate one for testing).
I kinda understand the basics of XML. The XML Code is not generated by me.. So i dont understand everything.

Comment: I tested my code on an XML document with two `MiddleCommand` under a common root element. What happens if you simply add a root element to the XML in the question (you can call it `root`; the name does not matter)?

Comment: The code presupposes a common root element (because that is what you have in the real XML document). `tree.findall(".//MiddleCommand")` searches for descendants. It does not work if XML document only contains a single `MiddleCommand` element.

Comment: I would love to. But i dont know how haha

Comment: Oh yeah that was easy haha.

Answer (score 0):

The below will find any `X` for you.

```
for x in root.findall(".//X"):
    print(x.text)
```

Comment: As mention in the comment above, I cant use that findall, because I need to differenciate between different types of "X"